# Do Rails sql query cache hit database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application I see a few 'cache' during SQL query in the server log:

> > [DEBUG] CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `regions`.* FROM `regions` WHERE `regions`.`name` = 'NY' LIMIT 1

I want to know if these caching are done by Rails, or by the MySQL itself? In another word, do these cached queries touch the database layer at all?

Comment: can you change accepted answer to other one?

Comment: @hlcs I don't know why the chosen answer got downvoted? Clearly it says the same thing as the other answer no?

Comment: @lulalaIa accepted answer says how to bypass chaching. The question is: do these cached queries touch the database.

Comment: @hlcs I guess chosen answer implies the "no" answer, provided with reference evidence which I felt more trustworthy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the following blog post on how to disable said feature its on rails cache and no the DB cache.

https://coderwall.com/p/tvybhq

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer to the question is "the caching is done by Rails; the queries do not ever get to the database".

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a source you can point to for more info?